# where should I store downloaded libraries that aren't on macports?

Tags: java, macos, scala

I've got a few 3rd party libraries Java and Scala libraries like Jung that aren't on MacPorts. Is there a standard, central place where people normally store libraries that they're likely to use on multiple projects?

Comment: wait, people use macports to install libraries?

Comment: @mattb Yeah, [check it commons libs, for example](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=commons). Don't know if you can specify versions or not. It's always seemed weird to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In their Maven repository?

Before Maven I just had a directory hierarchy that suited my purposes and kept directories under each library for different versions. Basically like Maven, although I organized it differently.

Comment: If you really hate maven you could also have a s3 bucket that you sync using s3cmd by calling "s3cmd sync s3://yourbucket /data/libraries". (I'd still use maven though)

Comment: @MatthewRathbone I still keep jar versions of a lot on Dropbox because I don't always have Maven, or it's not worth using. I do enjoy having cloud-like data ubiquity one way or another, more than I thought I would.

Comment: So is it ok to use both MacPorts and Maven at the same time? What's the difference between them?

Comment: maven is not the same thing, it's a java library package management framework. You can point it at public maven repos, or your own maven repos, so that when you compile your project it will auto-fetch dependencies

Comment: @bjz I've never understood dealing with Java libraries through MacPorts, except possibly for those with native components. I've always used it (until brew) as a way to get executables for OS X that are available on unix-like machines. Maven is... a lot of things, including a transitive dependency manager. I don't consider them even remotely alike. Personally, I would deal with all Java-only libraries through Maven, a workalike, or manually, giving you complete control.

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree with that, I like the dropbox idea, I might start using it myself :-).

Comment: cheers guys! Maven seems [to be on macports](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=maven).

Comment: @bjz I think you missed my point about using MacPorts for Java-only stuff. It may well work, but I'll continue to be curmudgeonly and do Java stuff myself.

Comment: @DaveNewton Oh yeah, I was only using it to install Maven it was real easy `sudo port install maven3` then `sudo port select --set maven maven3`. Now that's done I'm installing the libraries via Maven. It works for now! Just have to work out how to get everything into IntelliJ

Comment: @bjz I wouldn't even use it for that, but I need to switch between versions of Maven, so YMMV. If your project has a pom file you don't need to do anything else, it will detect the Maven file and guide you through it.

Comment: I don't understand why you would use macports to install Maven. All you need to do is download the zip/tar.gz, extract it, and add the bin location to your `$PATH`. Since it's a jar of compiled classes, you don't need to recompile the source on your target machine (unlike C or C++ applications/libs, which you would typically use MacPorts to install)